Combinations and Sub Combinations of Characters in a story
I was thinking about an old show and the number of characters in that show, how many combinations could there be.
In the Justice League show there are 7 superheroes. A, B, C, D, E, F, and G. I want to find out how many different combinations there are for a potential episode. Some of these where there are all 7 heroes, so thatd be 1 combination. Then there will be episodes where only 6 heroes are present, so there will be 7 combinations of those. And so on for 5 heroes, then 4 heroes, all the way to 1 hero. I got 127 different combinations by doing the combination calculator function (nCr) for each variation of r, where r can be 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, or 7, all out of a set of 7.
Now, I want to find out each subcombination for those combinations. So I'm looking for the subcombinations of the combinations of 7 heroes, and 6 heroes, and 5 heroes, etc. For instance, when all 7 are present, there will be one subcombination where A is seperated from the group, so A seperated from BCDEFG. Then another where B will be seperated. But also ones where both A and B are seperated.
I'm trying to figure out the total number of subcombinations within the 127 combinations of the 7 heroes. I'd appreciate the explanation on how this works instead of just the answer. Teach someone how to fish and all that.

You are just asking for the number of non-empty subsets of a set of size $n$, and that is $2^n-1$.  See, e.g., this post.

@lulu so this would be 2 ^(127) -1 or 2^(7)-1?

Here, you are looking for non-empty subsets of the set of the $7$ super heroes, so $n=7$ and the answer would be $2^7-1=127$, confirming your calculations.

If you’re asking how many nonempty subsets there are of an $n$-set of the 7 superheroes (where $1 \leq n \leq 7$), consider that one way to construct your subset is to consider in turn each of the $n$ potential members and decide whether that superhero should be included in your subset. This means that you will be making $n$ yes-or-no decisions, and thus all of that deciding has $2^n$ possible outcomes. So there are $2^n$ subsets, but you want to omit the one corresponding to $n$ no’s and zero yes’s. That’s why the number you seek is $2^n-1$.
By the way, this same argument proves that for any nonnegative integer $n$,
$$\sum_{k=0}^n {n \choose k} = 2^n ,$$
Where $k$ is the number of yes answers and $n \choose k$ is the number of ways those $k$ yes’s can be distributed among the $n$ elements.
Thus the sum of the entries in the $n$th row of Pascal’s triangle is $2^n$, as is the sum of the coefficients in the polynomial $(x+1)^n$. And that’s why $n \choose k$ is called a binomial coefficient, it’s the coefficient of $x^k$ when you raise the binomial $x+1$ to the $n$th power.

The number of subcombinations is (for $n=7$)
$$\begin{aligned}
& \sum_{k=1}^n \binom{n}{k} \sum_{j=1}^k \binom{k}{j} \\
&= \sum_{k=1}^n \binom{n}{k} (2^k-1) \\
&= \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} (2^k-1) \\
&= \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} 2^k  -  \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} 2^k \\
&= (2+1)^n - 2^n \\
&= 3^n - 2^n.
\end{aligned}$$
This answer can also be verified by the following combinatorial argument. For each character you decide to which group it belongs:

Not in the episode at all
In the episode, but not in the particular scene
In the particular scene (and hence of course in the episode)

So each character has $3$ choices and the ways to assign them is $3^n$. But we're also counting the "empty scenes" i.e. the assignments where each character is in 1. or 2. Hence we subtract this count $2^n$.

In the episode, we might have the character in question, or we may not, giving us 2 choices.
We have the same choice for 7 characters, so the total ways are
$2^7 - 1$,  we subtract the 1 for the scenario where no character is in the episode.
